# Specific styles for individual views

Tags: android, android-layout

Short question:
Is it possible to create a theme and set specific styles for individual views?

Lets say I want text color of TextView in red and text color for EditText in green.

Somithing like that (but this isn't working):

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">


    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>

    <style  parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>

    </style>
</style>
```

UPDATE:

The core element of my app are views I draw on my own. To support theming I have an abstract “Theme” base class which has methods to provide all colors and drawables I need. From this class I derive several classes like “BlackTheme”, “WhiteTheme”…
The user can set the right theme in Settings. For every additional information I need from the user I use a DialogFragment with default android widgets. In DialogFragments I apply the dialog style in the onCreateView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ReleaseNotesPopup viewLayout = new ReleaseNotesPopup(getActivity(), _callback, this);

    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(STYLE_NO_INPUT);


    viewLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(_Theme.popupBackground()));

    return viewLayout;
}
```

The core problem I have is that when I have a black background some widgets become invisible. Therefore i need custom selector's.Unfortunately you can't apply a widget style programmatically. Thats why I do this  the way as Joseph described in his answer:
attrs.xml

```
<resources>

<attr name="myEditTextStyle" format="reference" />
<attr name="myCheckBoxStyle" format="reference" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="WhiteTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppThemeBlack" parent="AppBaseTheme">


    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#b1b1b1</item>
     <item name="myEditTextStyle">@style/EditTextmyTime</item>
     <item name="myCheckBoxStyle">@style/CheckBoxmyTime</item>
</style>
```

I have added: style="?attr/myCheckBoxStyle" the all of my checkboxes.
If the BlackTheme is active I do setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme); in my Activity.onCreate()

For the BlackTheme I need special selectors because the default checked/unchecked icons are invisible when the background is black.

For a theme with a higher contrast, lets say WhiteTheme, I don't set the item "myCheckBoxStyle".

This implementaion works but I guess it is not optimal...

UPDATE2:

Here is my checkbox style. Downloaded from:http://android-holo-colors.com/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="EditTextmyTime" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/mytime_edit_text_holo_dark</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

 <style name="CheckBoxmyTime" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
  <item name="android:button">@drawable/mytime_btn_check_holo_dark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Enabled states -->



<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_pressed_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_pressed_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_focused_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_focused_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>

<!-- Disabled states -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_off_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mytime_btn_check_on_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want full control over individual elements (i.e. 2 textviews on a page might be different, or textviews on different pages might be different) but want it to be controllable by the theme:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="myTextAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="myEditTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myTextAppearance" format="reference" />
    <attr name="myEditTextStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**res/layout/layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/myTextAppearance"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Message Here"
        style="?attr/myEditTextStyle"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you don't want control over individual views, you can just override the defaults:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#0000ff</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res/layout/layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Message Here"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I want to avoid that because I don't want to add the style to each individual view. I want to set this once in a theme.

Comment: Additionally the user should have the possibility to change the theme in settings. I already have custom themes for the views I draw on my own. I accomplished this by implementing an abstract Theme class and several implementation which return theme specific colors and drawables...
The approach you posted above would not fulfill my needs since this would require a layout file per theme. Actually I just want so call “Activity.setTheme(R.drawable.RedTheme)” based on the users settings

Comment: Updated my answer and made it theme-able

Comment: Thanks! Going to read some documentation to understand what you posted above ^^

Comment: Ok, got it! That means that the answer to my question is: No, you can’t set a widget style in a custom theme for a specific widget type (like you can do in CSS-Style sheets). You have to create an alias and apply this to each widget. Do you agree?

Comment: The second part shows applying a style to all EditTexts without changing anything in your layout.xml -- but you do not have powerful selectors like CSS, you have to create attributes to control individual views

Comment: Ok, seems I don't got it completely. Can you tell me why my checkbox text isn't white when I just add:  <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>      to my AppTheme ?

Comment: I extended my question. I explained how I've implemented it. Would you please be so kind and read it and give me feedback?

Comment: You could avoid the attrs.xml entirely in your case by using `android:editTextStyle` and `android:checkBoxStyle` in your theme instead of your own attributes (you should remove the `style="?attr/myEditTextStyle` and same for checkbox from your layout as well in this case)

Comment: I update my question again. Now you should see everything I have. I tried to remove the style="?attr/myEditTextStyle just five minutes ago but my checkbox didn't get the correct icons anymore...

Comment: You need to have a theme, like `MyAppTheme` in my answer, that sets `android:editTextStyle` and `android:checkBoxStyle` to your custom styles.